# Gerar mais de um boleto com a DLL "Boleto.Net"

Tags: dll, boleto, c#

Eu percebi que a DLL [Boleto.Net](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet) tem uma classe `BoletoBancario` com a propriedade `FormatoCarne`. Porém, eu não consigo gerar três boletos em formato de carnê na mesma página.

Gostaria de visualizar um código que fizesse a impressão de 3 boletos em uma página, apenas.

Comment: Bom dia, conseguiu gerar o carnê? É com webforms ou MVC?

Comment: Dá erro, o que acontece?

Comment: Dudu Moreira, conseguiu imprimir mais de um boleto na mesma página?

Answer (score 1):

Bem, infelizmente eu não encontrei uma solução na própria biblioteca **Boleto.Net**, mas tive que implementar exatamente o mesmo requisito de três boletos em uma única folha, e por ter ainda que registrá-los, decidi gerá-los de maneira assíncrona. Então gerei os boletos separadamente, e depois os juntei através da biblioteca [PDFSharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp) com o código abaixo de minha autoria.

```
public static byte[] SinglePageCombine(List<byte[]> boletoList)
{
    var outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

    foreach (var boletoArray in boletoList)
    {
        var outputDocumentPageCount = outputDocument.PageCount;

        try
        {
            PdfDocument inputDocument = GetPdfDocument(boletoArray);

            var inputDocumentPageCount = inputDocument.PageCount;
            if (inputDocumentPageCount == 1)
            {
                int outputDocumentPageIndex;
                if (elementsInPage >= 1 && elementsInPage < 3)
                    outputDocumentPageIndex = outputDocumentPageCount - 1;
                else
                    outputDocumentPageIndex = outputDocumentPageCount;

                PdfPage outputDocumentPage = GetPdfPage(ref outputDocument, outputDocumentPageIndex);
                PdfPage inputDocumentPage = GetPdfPage(ref inputDocument, 0);

                double width = inputDocumentPage.Width,
                        height = inputDocumentPage.Height;

                SetPageDimensions(ref outputDocumentPage, width, height);

                XPdfForm xPdfForm = GetXPdfForm(boletoArray);
                var xRect = new XRect(0, elementsInPage * 280, width, height);

                using (var pdfXGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(outputDocumentPage, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append))
                {
                    pdfXGraphics.DrawImage(xPdfForm, xRect);
                }

                elementsInPage++;
                if (elementsInPage == 3)
                    elementsInPage = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Deve conter apenas uma página em cada boleto.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }

    byte[] outputDocumentBytes;
    using (var documentStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        outputDocument.Save(documentStream);
        outputDocumentBytes = documentStream.ToArray();
    }

    return outputDocumentBytes;
}

private static PdfDocument GetPdfDocument(byte[] fileContent)
{
    PdfDocument inputDocument;
    using (var documentStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent))
    {
        inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(documentStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
    }

    return inputDocument;
}

private static PdfPage GetPdfPage(ref PdfDocument pdfDocument, int pageIndex)
{
    var pdfDocumentPageCount = pdfDocument.PageCount;

    if (pageIndex < 0)
        pageIndex = 0;

    if (pdfDocumentPageCount == 0)
    {
        pdfDocument.AddPage();

    }
    else if (pageIndex > (pdfDocumentPageCount - 1))
    {
        var nextPage = pdfDocumentPageCount;
        if (nextPage == pageIndex)
            pdfDocument.AddPage();

    }

    return pdfDocument.Pages[pageIndex];
}

private static XPdfForm GetXPdfForm(byte[] fileContent)
{
    XPdfForm xPdfForm;
    using (var documentStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent))
    {
        xPdfForm = XPdfForm.FromStream(documentStream);
    }

    return xPdfForm;
}

private static void SetPageDimensions(ref PdfPage pdfPageToChange, double width, double height)
{
    pdfPageToChange.Width = width;
    pdfPageToChange.Height = height;
}
```